# Argument of type 'typeof GuestEntity' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CrudOptions'

Tags: nestjs

i have created module of guest this is my service.ts file

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { GuestsService } from './guests.service';

describe('GuestsService', () => {
  let service: GuestsService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [GuestsService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<GuestsService>(GuestsService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

this is my guest.entity.ts

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';
import { IsEmail } from 'class-validator';

@Entity({ name: 'guests' })
export class GuestEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  @IsEmail()
  email: string;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isPresent: boolean;
}
```

here is my controller.ts file

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Crud } from '@nestjsx/crud';
import { GuestsService } from './guests.service';
import { GuestEntity } from './guest.entity';
@Crud(GuestEntity)
@Controller('guests')
export class GuestsController {
  constructor(public service: GuestsService) { }
}
```

this is the error which I am facing in sevice.ts file
[image]
when I click on @crud(Guestentity) it gives me the following error
rgument of type 'typeof GuestEntity' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CrudOptions'.
Property 'model' is missing in type 'typeof GuestEntity' but required in type 'CrudOptions'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 0):

i have solved by giving type
@Crud({
model:{
type: GuestEntity,
},
})